# Android activity recognition wont update when device is in standby

Tags: android, google-play-services, intentservice, activity-recognition

I'm using **ActivityRecognitionClient** to get user's activities.

the problem is, as soon as the device is in standby mode, i stop getting updates, once i unlock the phone, i get updates.
i want to keep getting updates also when the device is in standby mode (screen is dimmed)
any one had this problem?

by the way, everything is made from a separated service

Thanks in advance,
Rotem.

Comment: Are you sure your internet connection stays alive when your phone goes to standby? Did you receive a onDisconnected()?

Comment: hey thanks for your comment, didn't get any onDisconnected event... i guess it does stay alive, LocationClient keep giving updates, GCM notifications arrive safetly...

Comment: Ion Aalbers, after some tests...i figured out that in higher api levels, it works just fine even in background. the device i worked with is a 2.3.6 version device (api 10)...so now it seems like i'm dealing with backward compatibility issues =\